# minimize alpha in exponential smoothing

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

I am new to use scipy and numpy on python.

My question: How do I minimize error function ( Mean absolute percentage error, MAPE to be specific) using an optimal alpha ( level smoothing constant)? So, I am trying to get optimal alpha through the MAPE.

Here's my math:

```
x = [ 3, 4, 5, 6]
y0 = x0
y1 = x0*alpha+ (1-alpha)*y0

MAPE = (y-x)/x [ This is an objective function and I am trying to solve for alpha here]

Constraints1: alpha<1
Constrants2 : alpha>0
```

Comment: Have you tried [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)?  For more information, see the [`scipy.optimize` tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

Comment: @askewchan. I am working on Least Square fitting and univariate function minimizers. I haven't had any luck. Would you be able to point to the right function? Thank you for your response

Comment: My first link is the function you want, I believe.  Build the function that you want to minimize w.r.t. `alpha`, pass it and a first guess to `scipy.optimize.minimize`, and it should return your optimal `alpha`.

Comment: I would help more, but I don't fully understand your problem as it is stated.  Is `y` supposed to be a vector of length 4 where `y[i+1] = x[i]*alpha + y[i]*(alpha-1)`?  I see only a definition of `y[0]` and `y[1]` but not `y[2]` or `y[3]`, but you have `x[0]` through `x[3]`.

Comment: @askewchan That's correct. If x = [3, 4, 5, 6], then y[i+1] = x[i]*alpha + y[i]*(alpha-1). x is the list of given value and y is the list of fitted value. Minimizing (y[i]- x[i])/x[i] will give me the best alpha.

Comment: So is there no dependence on `x[3]`? Oh I guess `y` does not depend on `x[3]`, but the `MAPE` does.

Comment: Yes that's correct. MAPE =  ((y[i]- x[i])/x[i])*1/4

Comment: @askewchan. That's correct

Comment: I don't understand what extra argument x does when you pass it into the minimizer.
how does the line [alpha_opt] = result.x give me optimal alpha. I am confused because of the variable x again? 

Thank you for your help, @askewchan.

Comment: @askewchan. The lower and upper bounds that are set in the code [(0,1)] are both exclusive, correct? How would I know the difference between exclusive and inclusive bounds?

Comment: Probably inclusive, i.e. `[0,1]`, when I run with your example `x`, my optimum `alpha` is `0`.  Documentation isn't clear to me, and perhaps there is no practical difference for numerical minimization?  I'm not actually an expert on this :P

Comment: @askewchan. Thank you for your help. I will be sure to comment when I find the right answer. :)

Comment: @askewchan. How do I use the function if I need to optimize three variables? I have uploaded my code, but I am having difficulty to minimize the MAPE again? The math behind to find the MAPE works so far. Its just that I am having difficulty minimizing the MAPE with three variables.

Comment: @askewchan, would you be able to help me on this matter?

Comment: I'll have to look into it later, maybe tomorrow.  You may be better off asking a separate question.

Comment: I already did. I have posted the entire code as well. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  I don't think there's a better way to find `y` than the recursion loop that I made.  The basic idea is that you need to make the thing you want to minimize into a function of the minimizing parameter (`alpha`) and anything else (`x`).  So, that's what I've called `mape`. Pass an initial guess for `alpha` and extra arguments (`x`) into the minimizer.  Since your constraints are just bounds, that is easy if you use `method='SLSQP'`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from __future__ import division

def y(alpha, x):
    y = np.empty(len(x), float)
    y[0] = x[0]
    for i in xrange(1, len(x)):
        y[i] = x[i-1]*alpha + y[i-1]*(1-alpha)
    return y

def mape(alpha, x):
    diff = y(alpha, x) - x
    return np.mean(diff/x)

x = np.array([ 3, 4, 5, 6])
guess = .5
result = minimize(mape, guess, (x,), bounds=[(0,1)], method='SLSQP')
```

To get your info, you can do:

```
print result
[alpha_opt] = result.x
```

Please comment if anything is confusing!

Comment: You must pass `x` to the minimizer because `mape` depends on `x` and `y` (and `y` in turn depends on `alpha`). Of course, you could make `x` a global variable that is defined as a constant within `mape`, but the functional style suggests that it should be passed as an argument.

Comment: Also, when you do `print result` it says `x: ...` and gives the optimum value of `alpha` it is called `x` not because of your `x`, but simply because that's what the optimum argument is called.  It is simply a coincidence that your input is called `x` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize



#coeffList[0] = alpha
#coeffList[1] = beta
#coeffList[2] =gamma

def mape(x, coeffList):
    diff = abs(y(x,coeffList)-x)
    print("np.mean(diff/x) : ", np.mean(diff/x))
    return np.mean(diff/x)


#Holt Winters-Multiplicative



def y(x, coeffList , debug=True):

    c =4 
    #Compute initial b and intercept using the first two complete c periods.
    xlen =len(x)
    #if xlen % c !=0:
    #    return None
    fc =float(c)
    xbar2 =sum([x[i] for i in range(c, 2 * c)])/ fc
    xbar1 =sum([x[i] for i in range(c)]) / fc
    b0 =(xbar2 - xbar1) / fc
    if debug: print ("b0 = ", b0)

    #Compute for the level estimate a0 using b0 above.
    tbar  =sum(i for i in range(1, c+1)) / fc
    print(tbar)
    a0 =xbar1  - b0 * tbar
    if debug: print ("a0 = ", a0)

    #Compute for initial indices
    I =[x[i] / (a0 + (i+1) * b0) for i in range(0, xlen)]
    if debug: print ("Initial indices = ", I)

    S=[0] * (xlen+ c)
    for i in range(c):
    S[i] =(I[i] + I[i+c]) / 2.0

    #Normalize so S[i] for i in [0, c)  will add to c.
    tS =c / sum([S[i] for i in range(c)])
    for i in range(c):
        S[i] *=tS
        if debug: print ("S[",i,"]=", S[i])

    # Holt - winters proper ...
    if debug: print( "Use Holt Winters formulae")


    At =a0
    Bt =b0
    #y =[0] * (xlen) 
    y = np.empty(len(x),float)
    for i in range(xlen):
        Atm1 =At
        Btm1 =Bt
        At =coeffList[0] * x[i] / S[i] + (1.0-coeffList[0]) * (Atm1 + Btm1)
        Bt =coeffList[1] * (At - Atm1) + (1- coeffList[1]) * Btm1
        S[i+c] =coeffList[2] * x[i] / At + (1.0 - coeffList[2]) * S[i]
        y[i]=(a0 + b0 * (i+1)) * S[i]

    return y


coeff = [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

x =[146, 96, 59, 133, 192, 127, 79, 186, 272, 155, 98, 219]
test = y(x,coeff)
print("test : ",test)

result = minimize(mape, coeff, (x,), bounds =[(0,1),(0,1), (0,1)], method='SLSQP')

opt = result.x
print("opt : ", result.x)
```